Ciscoのスイッチでvlan間ルーティングがしたい
L3の機能を利用してVLAN間ルーティングが上手くできません。
ポートごとにvlanを割り当てて、configモードでip routingと入力したのですがスイッチを介したホスト同士でpingができませんでした。
ちなみに機種は1200シリーズです

show ip routeの結果を質問文に追記すると回答を得られやすくなると思います。
